# Possible bug in InverseZTransform

Tags: integral-transforms

Try

```
x1n=InverseZTransform[1/(1-(1/z))//Factor,z,n]

x2n=InverseZTransform[1/(1-(1/z)),z,n]

DiscretePlot[x1n,{n,-10,10}]

DiscretePlot[x2n, {n,-10,10}]
```

The result is not what one would attend

Comment: Please include the results you expect. Also, if you are trying to report a purported bug, this is not the right place to do it (report it to Wolfram Support instead, if confirmed).

Comment: Mathematica uses the one-sided [`ZTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ZTransform.html#18764), so both are correct since they agree over the nonnegative integers.